# jqGrid not displaying JSON data

Tags: json, jqgrid

I've read some of the previous question and answers about this issue but couldn't understand why is not working for me.  I can see the grid but its empty and firebug don't give me any errors.

My JSON data is in this form

```
{"COLUMNS":["ID","MEMO"],"DATA":[[1,"test"],[2,"test1"],[3,"test2"]]}
```

I've tested that data using The [JSON Validator](http://jsonlint.com/) and it pass

my init code with the jsonReader

```
jQuery("#invoices").jqGrid({
    url:'/bob/index.cfm/invoices/read?format=json',
    datatype: "json",
    colNames:['id','memo'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id', width:255},
        {name:'memo', width:290}
    ],
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    pager: '#invoicespager',
    sortname: 'id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption:"JSON Example",
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        id: "Id",
        root: function (obj) { return obj; },
        page: function (obj) { return 1; },
        total: function (obj) { return 1; },
        records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
    }       

});
jQuery("#invoices").jqGrid('navGrid','#invoicespager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most JSON data can be read by jqGrid. You should just use the corresponding [jsonReader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data). To read your JSON data you can use

```
jsonReader: {
    repeatitems: true,
    id: "0",
    cell: "",
    root: "DATA",
    page: function() { return 1; },
    total: function() { return 1; },
    records: function(obj) { return obj.length; }
}
```

If you reduce the empty place in your grid with `height: 'auto'` you will see the following:

[image]

(see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Yannick.htm))