# Data still not displaying using jqGrid after doing some tips found around the net

Tags: php, javascript, jqgrid-php

I'm still having difficulty displaying data using jqGrid. I found some resources that might help me like the one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682240/jqgrid-not-displaying-json-data) and even copying the code found [here](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html).

I've been trying to solve this for so many hours but still I fail to do so. Can someone please help me? The following are the codes I currently have:

HTML/Javascript code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-  1.10.3.custom.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css"/>

<style>
html, body {
    margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-size: 75%;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery().ready(function (){
jQuery("#adminlist").jqGrid({
    url:'cnc_admin_search.php',
    datatype: "json",
    colNames:['Record ID','Admin ID', 'Password', 'Last Name','First Name','Type Code'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id',index:'id', width:55},
        {name:'adminid',index:'adminid', width:90, jsonmap:"adminid"},
        {name:'adminpass',index:'adminpass asc, adminid', width:100},
        {name:'lname',index:'lname', width:80, align:"right"},
        {name:'fname',index:'fname', width:80, align:"right"},      
        {name:'admintype',index:'admintype', width:80,align:"right"}
    ],
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    pager: '#adminpager',
    sortname: 'id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
    id: "id",
    root: function (obj) { return obj; },
    page: function (obj) { return 1; },
    total: function (obj) { return 1; },
    records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
    },
    caption: "JSON Mapping",
    height: '100%'
}).navGrid('#adminpager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});     
});
</script>

<title>Administrator Panel - Super Administrator</title>
</head>

<body>
<header>
    <h2>Administrator Panel - Super Administrator</h2>
</header>

<div class="content">
    <table id="adminlist"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
    <div id="adminpager"></div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP/Database Code:

```
<?php
$page = 1; // get the requested page
$limit = 10; // get how many rows we want to have into the grid
$sidx = 0; // get index row - i.e. user click to sort
$sord = 'desc'; // get the direction
if(!$sidx) $sidx =1;
// connect to the database
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')
or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db('caneco_db') or die("Error conecting to db.");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM caneco_admintable");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
$count = $row['count'];
if( $count >0 ) {
    $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit);
} else {
    $total_pages = 0;
}
if ($page > $total_pages) $page=$total_pages;
$start = $limit*$page - $limit; // do not put $limit*($page - 1)
if ($start<0) $start = 0;
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM caneco_admintable ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit";
$result = mysql_query( $SQL ) or die("Couldnt execute query.".mysql_error());
$responce->page = $page;
$responce->total = $total_pages;
$responce->records = $count;
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $responce->rows[$i]=$row;
    $i++;
} 
json_encode($responce); // coment if php 5     
break;  
?>
```

I hope someone will be able to help me. Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

I included the json data encoded by my php file:

```
{"page":1,"total":1,"records":"2","rows":[{"Admin_UserNum":"751497003","Admin_UserID":"jrmthibaler","Admin_Passwrd":"44c8ac3a1f03f006febc1075b2ba567d","Admin_LastName":"Hibaler","Admin_FirstName":"Jairo","Admin_TypeCode":"1"}, {"Admin_UserNum":"704006278","Admin_UserID":"rojaihibaler","Admin_Passwrd":"8810534d4f44d557d92a2110d664dcf6","Admin_LastName":"Hibaler","Admin_FirstName":"Jairo","Admin_TypeCode":"2"}]}
```

This was the JSON data produced by the php file I included previously. However there's an error saying 'Creating an object from empty value in Line 25' namely the following line of code:

```
 $responce->page = $page;
```

What could possibly be wrong with that line of code? The other two similar lines of code didn't generate the same error.